# Incorrect syntax near where - vba,sql

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have the below vba and I keep getting an error saying incorrect syntax near where.

```vb
Private Sub uplodblanks()

Dim ssql, r, c, con, dstring
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim lRow

con = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=0wcwlZq7hVeiu#S&bt;User ID=clx_write; Initial 
Catalog=DPEDataMartDBPrd01; Data Source=tcp:dscusnoramcloroxprd01.database.windows.net,1433;"

r = 1
c = 1
Worksheets("WTUpload").Calculate

'For i = 1 To 18
    'dstring = dstring & "'" & Sheets("WTUpload").Cells(5, i) & "' , "
'Next i
'dstring = dstring & "'" & Sheets("WTUpload").Cells(5, 19) & "'"

lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
cn.Open con

i = 1
For i = 1 To lRow
    ssql = "update dbo.cxu_all_load_control set driver_arr_dte = " & Sheets("WTUpload").Cells(i, 11) & " where mst_ship_num = " & Sheets("WTUpload").Cells(i, 11) & " ; "

    cn.Execute ssql

Next i

cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Show `debug.print ssql` output!

Comment: When you get the error, go to the debug window and type `? ssql` and press enter - when you do that, what is the exact string that it gives you? copy/paste it into your question at the end so everyone can see it.

Comment: @braX  set and criteria use same val, but diff types (see  Mohamads answer)

Comment: When i type ?ssql into the immediate window i get this: update dbo.cxu_all_load_control set driver_arr_dte =  where mst_ship_num =  ;

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert values into a date and a number like this :

```
ssql = "update dbo.cxu_all_load_control set driver_arr_dte = " & CDate(Sheets("WTUpload").Cells(i, 11)) & " where mst_ship_num = " & CDbl(Sheets("WTUpload").Cells(i, 11)) & " ; "
```

You can replace Cdbl(...) by the relevant function regarding the type of your mst_ship_num field.
But, I have one remark: why do you use the same Sheets("WTUpload").Cells(i, 11) to feed two different fields?

Another remark: this assumes that all values are correct. The best thing to do is to check the value of Sheets ("WTUpload"). Cells (i, 11) before using it in the query.

Comment: Im not sure about the WT upload part. The goal is to replace the null values in my database table with the values in one of the columns in the wokrbook. I ran what you put but got incorrect synatx near :

Comment: Better suggest using [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) or hope you never meet [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) ;)

Comment: If you are still using the same value Cells(i,11) for both [driver_arr_dte] and [mst_ship_num], it's normal to have the "incorrect syntax" message. Because, the value contained in Cells(i,11) cannot be converted into a date and a number at the same time. Do you have the possibility to use two distinct values for  [driver_arr_dte] and [mst_ship_num].

Comment: Im not sure about getting distinct values because the hope is that the tool will loop through and if the value is blank in the driver_arr_dte field it will take the filled in date in the excel file and update the database table by matching the mst_ship_num fileds

Comment: I believe part of my problem is the the sql statement is not being fully written in. When I am debugging and I hover over the ssql variable is says ssql=empty

Comment: Can you debug the value of lRow calculated in this line: 
lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row .     I think that you have lRow = 0.

Comment: When I debug and hover over lrow it says it is empty

Comment: How do I go about fixing the variable being empty?

Comment: Do you have the possibility to try manually to find "*" in your Worksheets("WTUpload") sheet ?  You can do this by selecting the A1 cells in this sheet and then Ctrl +F to do your search: beware of choosing As Part ., not Whole and by Formula..

Comment: When I do the search it basically just finds all the data in the worksheet

Comment: I recommend that you replace "*" with "PRODUCT()" in the multiplication formulas within your sheet. The code then becomes lRow = Cells.Find(What:="PRODUCT", After:=Range("A1"), ....